# load AngularJs controller, service from remote server (cross domain)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cross-domain

Is it possible to use an AngularJs controller and service that resides on a remote server?  I have some core functionality that I want to reuse in different AngularJs applications.  I do not want to make copies of this functionality.  How do you load AngularJs controller/service/directive/etc. from a remote server (cross domain)?

Comment: `<script src="http://mydomain.com/controller.js"></script>`

Comment: Check this out, see if it's helpful: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401271/angularjs-load-remote-js-controller-provided-by-webservice