# AngularJS load remote JS controller provided by webservice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have a AngularJS app, that depends on a webservice, I would like to load some more controllers into the app from a remote host, after the app is loaded. I don't know i this is possible?

In my controller, I want to load some more controllers (js files)

```
.controller('FrontpageCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $filter, $sce, contentService) {
    console.log("hitting FrontpageCtrl ... ");
    contentService.promise.then(function(data){
        var page = $filter('filter')(data, {id:$stateParams.pageId})[0];
        $scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(page.content);

        // Load a controller, directive and other provided by the webservice!
        $scope. ...
    });
})
```

Comment: I think you have to add this files dynamically to your app template (eg. in `<head>` section), and then reload the whole page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently angular does not provide a way to load modules dynamically. Hence, any angular built in object (directives, controllers, factories, etc.).
 This means your controllers (from the web service) should be loaded on bootsrapping angular (probably as a resource on the index page).

There are some ways to **dynamically** load stuff after bootstrapping, here are a few:

1. My personal favorite: https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad.
2. Closest to your question: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs
3. https://www.startersquad.com/blog/angularjs-requirejs/

There are many more stuff to be found.. you can obviously google it.